# Counterexample of "the product of open subsets is open in a topological ring"?

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups, topological-rings

Given a topological ring $R$ and $U,V$ open subsets, we can show that $U+V$ is an open subset due to the fact that $x\mapsto x+y$ is a homeomorphism for every $y \in R$. Since, in general, $R$ is not a division ring, it is not easy whether $UV$ is open or not.

My intuition tells me there must exist $R$ and $U,V$ open subsets such that $UV$ is not open, but I can't construct it.

Comment: Why is $UV$ open when $R$ is a division ring?

Comment: If $R$ is a division ring, you can prove easily that $x\mapsto xy$ is an homeomorphism. Using this, you prove that $aU$ is an open set for every $U$ open and $a\in R$. Taking unions, $AU$ is open for every $A\subset R$ and $U$ open. In particular, for every open $A$.

Comment: No, consider $y=0$ resp. $a=0$.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Suppose $\{0\}$ is not open (trivial case). $x\mapsto xy$ is an homeomorphism iff $y\neq 0$. This means $aU$ is open iff $a\neq 0$. So, let's take $U,V$ open sets. Suppose $0\notin U$, then $\displaystyle UV=\bigcup_{u\in U}uV$ so $UV$ it's open. Same if $0\notin V$. So take $0\in U\cap V$. Then $\displaystyle UV=\bigcup_{u\in U^*}uV \cup \{0\}$, but $\displaystyle \bigcup_{u\in U^*}uV$ contains zero since so does $V$. Thus $\displaystyle UV=\bigcup_{u\in U^*}uV$ and it's open.

(Which it's not true is that $AV$ is open for every $A\subset R$ and $U$ open)

Comment: You're right. But one has to consider the case $U^*=\emptyset$, i.e. $U=\{0\}$ extra (because then your set $\bigcup_{u \in U^*} uV=\emptyset$ does not contain zero). This case is of course quite trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a silly example: Let $A$ be any non-discrete topological abelian group. Endow it with the zero multiplication. Then $A$ is a non-unital topological ring and $UV=\{0\}$ is not open for all non-empty subsets $U,V$.

In order to get a unital example, consider the unitalization $\widetilde{A}$. The underlying abelian group is just $\mathbb{Z} \times A$, the multiplication is $(n,a) (m,b) = (nm,nb+ma)$, so that the unit is $(1,0)$. Let's endow $\mathbb{Z} \times A$ with the product topology, where $\mathbb{Z}$ carries the discrete topology. Then $\widetilde{A}$ is a unital topological ring. If $U,V$ are any non-empty open subsets of $A$, then $\{0\} \times U $ and $\{0\} \times V $ are open subsets of $\widetilde{A}$ with $(\{0\} \times U) \cdot (\{0\} \times V) = \{(0,0)\}$, which is not open.

It might be an interesting question to find conditions under which the product of two open subsets is again an open subset. For $\mathbb{R}$ the property is satisfied (Edit: in the comments it is shown for every topological division ring.). And I would be very surprised if it fails for $\mathbb{Z}_p$. More generally, I think that the property holds for many topological rings in practice.

Comment: Nice collection of examples. Just something: How do you know that the product topology is still a ring topology? I mean, can it be shown briefly or is it necessary to "get dirty"?

Comment: When working with products of spaces (or any objects...), you should always consider the universal property. Often there is no need to work with open subsets. We want to show that a certain map $* : A \times \mathbb{Z} \times A \times \mathbb{Z} \to A \times \mathbb{Z}$ is continuous. Hence, it suffices to show that the projected maps to $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are continuous. The first one is just the projection to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ followed by the multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}$, which is continuous since $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete.

Comment: The second is also a composition, built up out of the sum $+ : A \times A \to A$ (continuous by assumption) and the map $\mathbb{Z} \times A \to A$, $(n,b) \mapsto nb$ which is continuous since $\mathbb{Z} \times A \cong \coprod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} A$ and each $n : A \to A$ is continuous (by induction on $n$, using that $+ : A \times A \to A$ and $- : A \to A$ are continuous).